# How to simplify several functions with the same purpose

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

Let's say I have several functions that basically do the same thing but on a set of different variables. I think about something like that:

```
def changex():
    if x:
        # do procedure1 with x as variable
    else:
        # do procedure2 with x as variable

def changey():
    if y:
        # do procedure1 with y as variable
    else:
        # do procedure2 with y as variable

def changez():
    ...
```

How can I simplify that set of functions, such that I only have to write the function once but it does the job for all variables? I already looked into decorators which I think can do the job, but I can't make out how to make it work for my purpose.

Comment: Note that comparing e.g. `== True` is bad form, and I've simplified your logic as it wasn't relevant to the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Are you sure you want to edit the code like that instead of posting an answer?

Comment: @MadPhysicist ...what? The changes I've made were irrelevant to the question, and certainly didn't constitute an answer. If you mean why don't I write another answer, what's the point? There is already a good answer (twice!) and it's not like I need the rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions can accept variables as parameters.
Something like this:

```
def change(p):
    if p:
         # do procedure1 with p as variable
    else:
         # do procedure2 with p as variable
```

Then `changex()` becomes `change(x)`; `changey()` becomes `change(y)` etc.

Comment: Addendum for the novice's learning: You don't need to check `== True` or `== False` - if a `val` is "truthy", `if val` will execute that.

Comment: thanks for answer. I just want to extend it a little bit. Let's say I have variables which looks like `self.directionz, self.directiony, self.directionx`, which are used in other function. how do I adress them?

Comment: @kire `change(self.directionx)`, `change(self.directiony)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Decorators are way too complex for what you are trying to do. Functions can take arguments, so you can pass in the variable you want to do stuff with:

```
def change(var):
    if var:
        procedure1(var)
    else:
        procedure2(var)
```

Notice that I used `if/else` instead of checking both conditions with an `if`. I also recommend not testing explicitly against `True/False`. If you must do so, however, it is considered better practice to use `is` instead of `==` since `True` and `False` are singleton objects in Python: `if x is True` is better than `if x == True`.